# Query Mysql to find is a statement is valid (NOEXEC perhaps)

Tags: mysql

Is there any way in mysql to determine of a sql statement is valid before executing it?  (In other word rather than execute the stamens and deal with errors I simply want to know if it is a valid statement)

I notice in Mysql workbench that then I type a query it checks it for validity, so I assume there is a way to do that?

In essence I am trying to "precheck" the sql at runtime  to see if it is even valid with actually executing it.

Perhaps using the NOEXEC statement?

Comment: `explain your_query_here`? it won't execute, but definitely will complain if there's an error.

Comment: Thanks MArcB  But I am looking to 'Precheck' user input at runtime before I actually execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called 'SQL Fiddle', you have to build a schema first and then start running your sql queries, see link below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Thanks Muhammed.   SQL Fiddle is a great tool.  What I'm looking for is a way to check the query at runtime of an application before i actually execute it.